# Vb.net get primary key after inserting row in table adapter

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

Ok, I'm trying to simply add a new record to an access database in vb.net (ole.db).
I have a dataset and I have configured the data table.

After adding a row like this:

```
    Dim newRow As dataSet.MealsRow = dataSet.Meals.NewMealsRow
    newRow.mealName = "name"
    newRow.mealType = 12
    dataSet.Meals.AddMealsRow(newRow)
    tableAdapter.Update(dataSet.Meals)
    Dim tableId As Integer = newRow.Id
```

The tableId is always returing an incorrect primary key value.
If I leave the `AutoIncrementSeed` to -1 and `AutoIncrementStep` to -1 in the `Data Table`, then the tableId will have negative values starting from -1 and going down, -2, -3, etc...

Shouldn't it picking up the correct key value inserted there ?

Comment: Thats not how it works at least with a DataAdapter.  When you update, it doesnt read back the actual DB-supplied AI PK value.  If the DA knows the schema, you can invoke a new `Fill` to get the new rows, then remove (not delete) those with a negative ID.

Comment: I just want to add a new row and get the primary key

Comment: What you want to do is easier with providers that support multiple SQL statements per command.  For instance, with the `SqlClient` provider for SQL Servr, you simply add something like `SELECT ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after your INSERT statement and your `DataTable` will be updated with the auto-generated identity values.  With Access, it's a bit more involved.  Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, it worked. I've seen simmilary solutions, but when adding `Select Scope_Identity()' I would get an sql parse error in the  dataset designer, query builder... Even with the above example, the `Select @@Identity' statement, returns an error in the query builder, but it works.... If you'd like post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as correct

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm fairly sure that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is specific to SQL Server.  As for using `@@IDENTITY`, I did mention in a later post in that thread that it works with a typed `DataSet` despite the query builder not liking it.  I won't post an answer because I've only provided a link and I don't feel inclined to dig out the relevant code myself.  Feel free to post the code that you used in an answer and accept that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is specific to SQL Server, but I was also trying with `@@Identity' and because I was getting the query builder syntax error I didn't try it. Thank you!